# How to create strings inside of a Nim formatted string

Tags: nim-lang

I'm doing something like this:

```py
echo &"verse #{v.number}: {v.translated} ({v.words.map(w => w.greek).join()})"
```

However I'd like to join using a space (`" "`)
Yet,

```py
&"{v.words.map(w => w.greek).join(' ')}"
```

and

```py
&"{v.words.map(w => w.greek).join(` `)}"
```

won't work.

Is there a way to create strings inside of a string interpolation expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the `"`:

```
&"{v.words.map(w => w.greek).join(\" \")}"
```

Comment: Oh, I thought this would be interpreted as a litteral `"`, it works. Thanks.